# How to check that class attribute contain particular class or not?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Here is my code.
It's yielded all classes. I want to check that there is 'mat-checked' class is included.

```
pmanage.no_additional_cost().last().invoke('prop', 'class').then((Class) => {
                let Pclass = Class
               cy.log(Pclass)
                            if(Pclass.contains('mat-checked')){
                                cy.log('mat-checked found')
                                cy.writeFile(filename, Pclass)
                            }else{
                                cy.log('Toggle is off')
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.includes` to check whether `mat-checked` is present in your class value.

```js
pmanage.no_additional_cost().last().invoke('prop', 'class').then((Class) => {
  let Pclass = Class
  cy.log(Pclass)
  if (Pclass.includes('mat-checked')) {
    cy.log('mat-checked found')
    cy.writeFile(filename, Pclass)
  } else {
    cy.log('Toggle is off')
  }
})
```

You can also use `invoke('attr', 'class')`

```js
pmanage.no_additional_cost().last().invoke('attr', 'class').then((classValue) => {
  if (classValue.includes('mat-checked')) {
    cy.log('mat-checked found')
    cy.writeFile(filename, classValue)
  } else {
    cy.log('Toggle is off')
  }
})
```